# Protocol type cannot be instantiated

Tags: initialization, swift3, protocols

Consider the following code:

```
protocol Color {
    var color: UIColor { get }
}

struct Ball : Color {
    var color: UIColor
}

let ball = Ball(color: .white)
print(ball)
```

This works, and results in:

```
Ball(color: UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1)
```

Now, I would like to make a function in the protocol, that given an array of colors, returns an array of items (balls, or any other type that conforms to `Color`) with that color:

```
extension Color {
    func multipleColors(colors: [UIColor]) -> [Color] {
       var coloredItems = [Color]()
       for item in colors {
        // What do I put here ???
       }

       return coloredItems
    }
}
```

and then:

```
let coloredBalls = ball.multipleColors(colors: [.red, .green, .blue])
```

I cannot figure out what to put inside the brackets.  For instance (no pun), if I try:

```
coloredItems.append(Color(color: item))
```

the error is:

```
'Color' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

I then added an init method to the protocol, and the error changed to:

```
protocol type 'Color' cannot be instantiated
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You are trying to create an instance of a protocol `Color(color: item)`, which is not possible.

Comment: So any ideas how to change this?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you expect the output of your `multipleColors` function to be. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: So given an item that conforms to the `Color` protocol (eg `Ball`, or `Bike` or `Sweater`), I would like to return an array of that item with different colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of a protocol `Color(color: item)`, which is not possible.

Find one possible generic solution below. I could not find a non-static (nice) solution so far.

```
protocol Color {
    var color: UIColor {get set}
    init(color: UIColor)
}

struct Ball : Color {
    var color: UIColor
}

extension Color {
    static func item<T:Color>(_ item: T, inColors colors: [UIColor]) -> [T] {
        var coloredItems = [T]()
        for color in colors {
            let newColoredItem = T.init(color: color)
            coloredItems.append(newColoredItem)
        }

        return coloredItems
    }
}

let ball = Ball(color: .white)
let coloredBalls = type(of:ball).item(ball, inColors: [.red, .green, .blue])

print(coloredBalls)
```

Prints:

```
[Ball(color: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1), Ball(color: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1), Ball(color: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1)]
```

Comment: I like this solution, and will accept it since it answers the question. However, `Ball` also has more properties such as `size` (which I omitted for clarity), and those also need to be propagated to `coloredItems`.

Comment: I considered this as a rather theoretically example. In practice use a class. You want to know if `alicesBall === bobsBall`. Also I would Delete `Color`. Create `class ColoredItem { var color: UIColor func multipleColors()...`. And subclass it .

Comment: Also you could imblement a `copy` function and use it: `T.copy()` instead of `T.init()`.